# OneDrive CSharp SDK and OneDrive REST API - how to determine if a document is a file or folder?

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am coding against the `OneDrive C# SDK` and I am trying to see if the `Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Item`class has any property where it states if an item is a Folder or a File?

I took a look in the `Item` class in the `Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk` namespace but nothing popped out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is distinguised by the following properties:

- a folder has the `Folder` property non-null
- a file has the `File` property non-null

See the `Item` class [source](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/src/OneDriveSdk/Models/Generated/Item.cs) and the underlying API's [documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm) stating:

> Items have Facets that provide data about the `item`'s identities and capabilities. Folders have a `folder` facet and files have a `file` facet. Images have an `image` facet in addition to their `file` facet.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

For the C# SDK, you can determine it by the item's property [`Folder`](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/src/OneDriveSdk/Models/Generated/Item.cs#L131) and [`File`](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/src/OneDriveSdk/Models/Generated/Item.cs#L119)